# Trying to understand async await

Tags: javascript, async-await

I'm trying to understand why this piece of code doesn't behave as I expect:

```js
async function test() {
  await setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('done')
  }, 1000)

  console.log('it finished');
}


test();
```

This first prints `it finished` and then prints `done` afterwards. Shouldn't this code wait for the timeout to finish before executing `console.log('it finished');` or have I misunderstood something?

Comment: why are you using `await` on `setTimeout`? it's not a promise

Comment: you should have a look at promises and how they work in general

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to setTimeout on async await call node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50091857/how-to-settimeout-on-async-await-call-node)
And Maybe the title should be like _Trying to await setTimeout not working_

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can only usefully `await` a [promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).

`setTimeout` returns a timeout id (a number) that you can pass to `clearTimeout` to cancel it. It doesn't return a promise.

You could wrap `setTimeout` in a promise…

```js
async function test() {
  await new Promise( resolve => setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('done');
    resolve("done");
  }, 1000));

  console.log('it finished');
}


test();
```