# can i make the async.retry method retry even on successfull queries but based on a condition

Tags: javascript, node.js, async.js

I'm studying the node.js module async,I want to find out if there is a way to  change the  async.retry method to retry even on successfull operations but stop based on some condition or response let's say its an api call.

According to its [docs](https://caolan.github.io/async/v3/docs.html#retry) ,the function will continue trying the task  on failures  until it succeeds.if it succeeds it will only run only that time  But how can i make it work the same on successfull operations and make it stop on some condition ?

```
const async = require('async');
const axios = require('axios');

const api = async () => {
    const uri = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1';

    try {
        const results = await axios.get(uri);
        return results.data;
    } catch (error) {
        throw error;
    }
};

const retryPolicy = async (apiMethod) => {
    async.retry({ times: 3, interval: 200 }, apiMethod, function (err, result) {
        // should retry untill the condition is met
        if (result.data.userId == 5) {
            // stop retring
        }
    });
};

retryPolicy(api);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, You can just throw a custom error if condition is not met. Would be something like that:

```
const async = require('async');
const axios = require('axios');

const api = async () => {
    const uri = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1';

    try {
        const results = await axios.get(uri);
        if(typeof result.data.userId != 'undefined' && result.data.userId == 5){ // change this condition to fit your needs
            return results.data;
        }else{
            throw {name : "BadDataError", message : "I don't like the data I got"}; 
        }
    } catch (error) {
        throw error;
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks. this seems to work. what would you advise in terms of scalability.can this handle 0ver 1000 requests properly?

Comment: Yes, there should be no problem with that

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible.
On the [async.retry documentation](https://caolan.github.io/async/v3/docs.html#retry) you can find this description:

> Attempts to get a successful response from task no more than times
> times before returning an error. If the task is successful, the
> callback will be passed the result of the successful task. If all
> attempts fail, the callback will be passed the error and result (if
> any) of the final attempt.

However, using the delay function given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50091857/how-to-settimeout-on-async-await-call-node), you can do what you want another way:

```js
const async = require('async');
const axios = require('axios');

const delay = (t, val) => {
   return new Promise((resolve) => {
       setTimeout(() => { resolve(val) }, t);
   });
}

const api = async () => {
    const uri = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1';

    try {
        const results = await axios.get(uri);
        return results.data;
    } catch (error) {
        throw error;
    }
};

const retryPolicy = async (apiMethod) => {
    const times = 3
    const interval = 200
    let data

    for (count = 0; count < 3; count++) {
        try {
            data = await apiMethod()
        catch(e) {
            console.log(e)
            await delay(interval)
            continue
        }
        if (data.userId === 5) {
            break;
        }

        await delay(interval)
    }
   
    // do something
};

retryPolicy(api);
```

Comment: Thanks. is this scalable lets say in an environement where you receive over 1000 requests and for each request i run this code snippet for like 1 minute per request?

Comment: but there is an easier way... just fail the request with throwing the error if the data doesn't fit your needs, it the request itself, check my answer

Comment: I indeed think Flash's answer is much simplier than mine and that does exactly what you want.

Comment: I don't relly know, but i think running this code for 1min per request might be somehow heavy. But i don't see another way to do what you want a more lightly way